# Trying to access DateTime object to retrieve date property

Tags: php

I am trying to access a a property of this object:

```
    object(DateTime)#321 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2016-08-02 12:45:01.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/London"
}
```

I have tried this:

```
$boo = aboveObject;
$boo->date;
```

I get this error:

```
 "Notice: Undefined property: DateTime::$date"
```

I have also tried this:

```
$foo = aboveObject;
$foo['date']
```

I get this error:

```
"Error: Cannot use object of type DateTime as array"
```

of course the second error makes more sense to me bur the first way i tried should be working...? any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

You can get date by this way:

```
 $dateObj = new DateTime();
 echo $dateObj->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 2):

The `date` property does not normally exist in a `DateTime` object. It is only added by `print_r` or `var_dump` in order to show you the contents of the object. You can see this by doing:

```
$boo = new DateTime;
echo $boo->date;
```

Which will get you a "Notice: undefined property", and then:

```
$boo = new DateTime;
print_r($boo);        // or var_dump($boo);
echo $boo->date;
```

which will successfully echo the added date property.

This is obviously *not* the correct way to get at this "property", however. You should use the [`format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method as others have suggested to output the date in any format you want.